# Reducing the space between plots in GraphicsGrid?

Tags: plotting, graphics, grid-layouts

I am using GraphicsGrid to produce the following figure:

```
Plot1 = Plot[Exp[-0.03*t], {t, 0, 300}, 
   AxesLabel -> {None, "testing1"}];

GraphicsGrid[{{Plot1}, {Plot1}}]
```

Is there a way to control how much space is between the two plots?

Comment: `Spacings -> -2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cvgmt gave you the answer, but I would like to elaborate a bit. When using `GraphicsGrid` the pain has to do with the `AspectRatio` if I am not mistaken. Instead you can use `Grid`. Using `Grid` is not a golden hammer and it has its downsides from certain points of view; I think that every time I have used it I had to adjust the `ImageSize`, but I still find it easier to manipulate in most situations. I suggest that you experiment a little bit in each given situation.

Below I am giving 3 alternatives.

```
Plot1 = Plot[Exp[-0.03*t], {t, 0, 300}, 
   AxesLabel -> {None, "testing1"}];
GraphicsGrid[{{Plot1}, {Plot1}}, Spacings -> 0, 
 AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

> [image: graphicsgrid]

```
Plot1 = Plot[Exp[-0.03*t], {t, 0, 300}, 
  AxesLabel -> {None, "testing1"}, ImageSize -> Medium];
Grid[{{Plot1}, {Plot1}}, Spacings -> {0, 0}]
```

[image: grid]

```
ResourceFunction["PlotGrid"][{{Plot1}, {Plot1}}, Spacings -> 25]
```

> [image: resource]

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: @mathbioguy glad I was able to help :) thanks for the accept